# The POM is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Parent pom has dependencyManagement for spring-boot-dependencies version 2.5.4. Still I get this warning for child pom mvn build:

> The POM for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz:jar:2.5.4 is missing, no dependency information available

Comment: Please share your `pom.xml`

Comment: Please check plain command line ...also check if there are some warning during the build...because it could be a network/proxy/firewall issue?

Answer (score 0):

Declarations in [`<dependencyManagement>`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Management) do nothing but being a template for the configuration once a dependency is used in `<dependencies>` later on.

Comment: Please suggest how we can resolve it.

Comment: @sum https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management